# Return statement is Not exiting the function - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

**Issue**

In the response i get the payload as specified in the payload structure, the only difference is instead of **FAILED**, sometimes I get **SUCCESS**, other times I get **RUNNING**.

From the gist of the code, if you notice, that if the status in the response is anything but **SUCCESS/FAILED**, then we are recalling the **schedule_status** function till the time the response changes to either **SUCCESS or FAILED**

Upon **FAILURE/SUCCESS**, I'm trying to create a dictionary of status and status_reason for further usability. However the code is going into a recursion and is not ending.

After return statement in the **schedule_status**, the line is going and executing the **hlpr.schedule_status(id)** in the else block of the **schedule_iterator**

Expectation is to exit after the return statement of the **schedule_status** is executed.

**Payload Structure**

```
{'jobs': [{'status': 'FAILED', 'status_reason': 'Could not Acquire Lock on Instance::i-0053d13fsadb94c6', 'updated_at': '2022-03-09T07:51:21.014749+0000', 'user_approval': []}], 'count': 1}
```

**Caller Function looks like this**

```
message = HelperFun.schedule_status(id)
print(message)
```

**Backend Code**

```
class HelperFun:

    @staticmethod
    def schedule_status(id):
    
        mrt = MakeRequest()
        pct = PayloadCreator()
        hlpr = HelperFun()
        url = ENDPOINT_BASE_PATH + MW_SCHEDULE_STATUS_API_PATH
        payload = pct.schstatusPayload(id)
        response = mrt.make_api_call(url=url, **payload)

        if not response['jobs']:
                sleep(20)
                dvr.schedule_status(dave_id)
                
        if response['jobs'][0]['status'] == "SUCCESS" or response['jobs'][0]['status'] == "FAILED":
            message = {'status': response['jobs'][0]['status'],
                            'status_reason': response['jobs'][0]['status_reason']}
        else:
            sleep(20)
            dvr.schedule_status(dave_id)
        return message
```

***Desired Output***

```
{'status': 'FAILED', 'status_reason': 'Could not Acquire Lock on Instance::i-0053d13fsadb94c6' }
```

**ERROR**

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'message' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Both functions are calling each other. You have to remove this recursion from your code.

Comment: `return` only stops the function that it is called in and goes back to the one that called it. In your case, `schedule_status` was called from `schedule_iterator` so that is where it will return to.

Comment: @matszwecja - but i'm returning the schedule_status with the message right ?

Comment: @KlausD. - how do i do that, any example would help.

Comment: Yes, you are returning it - to `hlpr.schedule_status(id)`. And then you go on to `while True`

Comment: As you told, i got rid of the other function, but in simplified mechanism, i'm getting the following error. Mentioned below.
@matszwecja

Comment: What is `dvr` in your simplified example?

Comment: You say `return message`, but sometimes `message` is not assigned a value since it only is on one route in the `if/else`